# cordova + angularjs route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I don't understand why my app doesn't works when i call a view with some route..
I use one js file app.js and some html page.
I probably miss something :(

here is my code :

app.js

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    // Lancement appli
}, false);

function TestCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.status = "It works!";
}

function ViewCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.status = "Also totally works!";
}
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: TestCtrl
        })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'about.html',
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home',
            controller: ViewCtrl
        });
    }]);
```

index.htlm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <!--
        Personnalisez la stratégie de sécurité de contenu dans la balise meta ci-dessous selon vos besoins. Ajoutez 'unsafe-inline' à default-src pour activer JavaScript directement dans les lignes.
        Pour obtenir des détails, consultez http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=617521
    -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">


    <link href="plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="plugins/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>

    <title>Maquette</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        Appli One
    </header>
    <section class="view" ng-view></section>

    <nav class="footer">
        <div>
            <a href="#/home"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="color:white;font-size:30px;"></span></a>
            <a href="#/about"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" style="color:white;font-size:30px;"></span></a>
        </div>
    </nav>


</body>
</html>
```

Many thank for help

Answer (score 0):

I made a Plunker that could help you to understand `$routeProvider`.

http://plnkr.co/edit/aLWgMZ2uJWZEBFXxtzbU?p=preview

As you can see, I prefer define my controller in my view, not in my .config. If you want to keep the Controllers in `app.config`, don't forget to write your controllers name between quotes.

If you need more explanations, or details, please tell me more about your issue.

> *"I don't understand why my app doesn't works"*

This is not enough for understand what is the real problem in your app.

Comment: HEllo,Yes sorry i forget some details. My <a> link doesn't works, that is the problem. I'll take a look at your plunker this evening. thanks
Hope that this gone help me

Comment: Np, don't hesite to back here and tell me if it fits to your project

Comment: i think ur plunker doesn't works no ? the link doesn't works for me

Comment: i tried to add quote to my controller but it changes nothing..:(